# Wordpress procurar por post

Tags: php, wordpress, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho uma questão pertinente e que já ando à tempos a tentar resolver. 
No meu website tenho 2 modos search personalizados e em páginas diferentes, no entanto ao criar o 3º vejo os resultados na página mas não consigo usar o bloco de  procura.
Alguém que consiga dar uma luz...

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    // custom search 
    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'custom_search_join' );
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_search_where' );
    add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'custom_search_groupby' );
}

// search with join
function custom_search_join($join) {
    if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {
        global $wpdb;
       $join = " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ";
    }
    return($join);
}

// search with groupby
function custom_search_groupby($groupby) {
    if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $groupby = " $wpdb->posts.ID ";
    }
    return($groupby);
}

        // search with where
        function custom_search_where($where) {
            global $wpdb;
            $old_where = $where;
            if (is_search() && isset($_GET['s']) && !isset($_GET['segundo_search']))
        {
                // add additional custom fields here to include them in search results
                $customs = array('_mais1', 'mais2', '_mais3', 'mais4');
                $query = '';
                $var_q = stripslashes($_GET['s']);
                preg_match_all('/".*?("|$)|((?<=[\\s",+])|^)[^\\s",+]+/', $var_q, $matches);
                $search_terms = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return trim($a, "\\"\'\\n\\r ");'), $matches[0]);

                $n = '%';
                $searchand = '';
                foreach((array)$search_terms as $term) {
                    $term = addslashes_gpc($term);
                    $query .= "{$searchand}(";
                    $query .= "($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                    $query .= " OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                    foreach($customs as $custom) {
                        $query .= " OR (";
                        $query .= "($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$custom')";
                        $query .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value  LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                        $query .= ")";
                    }
                    $query .= ")";
                    $searchand = ' AND ';
                }
                $term = $wpdb->escape($var_q);
                $where .= " OR ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                $where .= " OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";

                if (!empty($query)) {
                    $where = " AND ({$query}) AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish') AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'primeiro_listing')";
                }
            } else if (is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {

            // added custom fields here to include them in search results
                $customs = array(
                    '_1',
                    '_2',
                    '_3'
                );
                $query = '';
                $searchand = '';
                foreach((array)$search_terms as $term) {
                    $term = addslashes_gpc($term);
                    $query .= "{$searchand}(";
                    $query .= "($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                    $query .= " OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                    foreach($customs as $custom) {
                        $query .= " OR (";
                        $query .= "($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$custom')";
                        $query .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value  LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                        $query .= ")";
                    }
                    $query .= ")";
                    $searchand = ' AND ';
                }
                $term = $wpdb->escape($var_q);
                $where .= " OR ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
                $where .= " OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";

                if (!empty($query)) {
                    $where = " {$old_where} AND ({$query}) AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish') AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'segundo') ";        
                    }
            }
            return($where);
        }
```

**Formulário:**

```
<?php global $app_abbr, $header_search; $header_search = true; ?>

<?php if (get_option('jr_show_searchbar')!=='no' && ( !isset($_GET['submit']) || ( isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit']!=='true' ) ) && ( !isset($_GET['myjobs']) || ( isset($_GET['myjobs']) && $_GET['myjobs']!=='true' ) ) ) : ?>

    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/" method="get" id="searchform">

        <div class="search-wrap">

            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="terceiro_search" value="true" />
                <input type="text" id="search" title="" name="s" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Search Terceiros',APDB); ?>" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['s'])) echo esc_attr(get_search_query()); ?>" />
                <input type="text" id="near" title="<?php _e('Location',APDB); ?>" name="location" class="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Location',APDB); ?>" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['location'])) echo esc_attr($_GET['location']); ?>" />
                <label for="search"><button type="submit" title="<?php _e('Go',APDB); ?>" class="submit"><?php _e('Go',APDB); ?></button></label>

                <input type="hidden" name="ptype" value="<?php echo esc_attr( POST_TYPE_TERCEIRO ); ?>" />

                <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="field_latitude" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="field_longitude" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="full_address" id="field_full_address" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="north_east_lng" id="field_north_east_lng" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="south_west_lng" id="field_south_west_lng" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="north_east_lat" id="field_north_east_lat" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="south_west_lat" id="field_south_west_lat" value="" />
            </div>

        </div><!-- end search-wrap -->

    </form>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teria de mandar o seu `form action` para um o local aonde a busca é processada pelo que estou vendo no código:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/" method="get" id="searchform">
```

Ele esta enviando para a URL inicial do WP também o `id` do `form` deve ser alterado.

Você pode verificar nos outros dois `forms` o que eles tem de similar e seguir a mesma regra.

Caso queira postar os outros dois poderei ajudar você melhor.

Comment: Obrigada desde já pela sua resposta. Acabei por colocar um formulário com dados mais complexos e ele automaticamente foi buscar o formulário. Apenas tive de mudar o id...no entanto quando esta situação voltar a acontecer já sei como resolver. Muito obrigada